# How interface works with generics subtyping in java?

Tags: java

Consider the following classes.

```
class Shape {}
class Circle extends Shape {}
class Rectangle extends Shape {}

class Node <T> {}

// In main method
Node<Circle> circleNode = new Node<>();
Node<Shape> shapeNode = circleNode; // ERROR
```

Following code will not compile because even though Circle is a subtype of Shape. Because of generics subtyping.

But now consider the new Node class.

```
class Node<T> implements Comparable<T> {
    public int compareTo(T obj) { /* ... */ }
    // ...
}

// In main method
Node<String> stringNode = new Node<>();
Comparable<String> comparable = stringNode;
```

Following code successfully compile. But there is no explanation on Java Docs. How implementing an interface make it compile successfully. And I didn't understand what happened exactly.

Comment: The 2nd example is not using parent/subclasses like the first one.

Comment: Yes, but how is it working. That's what i want to know. Please correct me, if i'm not clear enough with my question. Thanks

Comment: @HimanshuBisht you can do `Node<? extends Shape> shapeNode = circleNode;`

Comment: You're comparing two different things. You can assign a child object to a parent variable type. But you can't do that with generics, like in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing apples and oranges.

In your example, `Node<Shape>` is to `Node<Circle>` as `List<Animal>` is to `List<Dog>`.
However, `Comparable<String>` is to `Node<String>` as `List<Animal>` is to `ArrayList<Animal>`.

If you can have this parallelism clear in mind, all you need to remember is that a `List<Dog>` *is not* a `List<Animal>` and you have your answer.

`stringNode` is a `Node<String>`, and that means assigning that variable to a `Comparable<String>`-typed variable only requires the base type's relationship. That's because the declaration `Node<T> implements Comparable<T>` makes `Node` a `Comparable` subtype. With the type parameter being exactly the same, that makes `Comparable<String>` assignable from `Node<String>` (just as `List<String>` is assignable from `ArrayList<String>`)

In other words, the difference is not due to *"implementing an interface make it compile successfully"*... it's due to the fact that `Node<Shape>` is not assignable from `Node<Circle>` (which you seem to understand), whether node is an interface or not.

Comment: So that basically means, when when we implements or extends a type like Comparable<T> in this case, then it makes Node<T> its subtype. So after that we can perform parent-child subtyping as usual, provided that their type arguments are same.

Comment: Assuming the declaration is like yours (where the type parameter is declared identically and passed to the supertype the way you pass it), yes; @HimanshuBisht

Comment: @ernest_k Thank you so much. It really helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In 2nd example you're saying that for a given `T` a `Node<T>` is a `Comparable<T>`. Thus, for `T = String` you have `Node<String>` is a `Comparable<String>`.

However in 1st example you have 2 different types `T` and `U` where `T` is a `U` but there is nothing that says that `Node<T>` is a `Node<U>`.

You might want to look for *covariance* and *contravariance* to learn more on this topic.